# iptables with host-only VM losing host connectivity

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm following the cuckoo docs to set it up on its own machine, which is connected to the network via LAN. I've created my first VM and created a host-only network to allow the VM to talk to the host. The guide then tells me to set up the ofllowing iptables rules:

```bsh
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.56.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

# Default drop.
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Existing connections.
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Accept connections from vboxnet to the whole internet.
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# Internal traffic.
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.56.0/24 -d 192.168.56.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# Log stuff that reaches this point (could be noisy).
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
```

As soon as I set these rules up, the VM is able to access the internet, but the host loses its internet connectivity. It can still ping. I have no other rules in place.

Any ideas as to why this happens? I can't find anything online.

Comment: What is the default policy for INPUT and OUTPUT please (you could post `iptables -nvL` while it isn't working to show us)?